# How to get index of image from ListView on onmouseover event?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a ListView that shows images and I can get the index of the image once I click on it, but not able to get the index when I only hover on the image.

This is where I am:

```
<img onmouseover="ImageListHover(this, $(this));" id="#=ItemID#" src="../Images/CatalogImages/#= CheckForImagesURL(FilePreview) #" alt="#: ItemName # image" />
```

The function that is being called on the mouseover event is:

```
function ImageListHover(a, b) {
    console.log("index from a is: " + a.index());
    console.log("index from b is: " + b.index());
}
```

I am passing over both this and $(this) to see if I can get the index from either of those but to no avail.

**EDIT**

Here is a link to the code, I had to place it on the kendo dojo because I am using an example that I modified..[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ChrisW76/iKecudAH)

Comment: `b.index()` should work. It would help to see a more complete sample of your HTML to diagnose the issue, though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Good idea, I'll add a more complete example...It'll be about 20 minutes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I provided a link in my edit

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much clearer - I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `img` elements you're targeting are not siblings, hence they are all at index `0` within their respective containers.

To fix this, provide a selector to `index()` which explicitly specifies the collection within which you want to retrieve the index within:

```
function ImageListHover(a, b) {
  console.log("index from b is: " + b.index('.product img'));
}
```

Also note that using `on*` event attributes is an outdated technique which should be avoided. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead:

```
$(function() {
  // your kendo setup here...

  $('.product img').on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log($(this).index('.product img'));
  });
});
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks, and thank you for the explanation and both examples, its much appreciated